# Local area connection properties -> IPv4 displaying DHCP on while using static IP

Tags: networking, windows-7, configuration

This seems weired to me:

After I installed Windows7 (7000) I've set IPv4 properties of my NIC to a static IP and DNS.

But when I'm looking into the IPv4 properties of the NIC now, both IP and DNS are set to "Obtain automatically" while the NIC sill has the static IP I've set earlier (As I can verify with ipconfig or in the "Network connection details" for the adapter).

Can anybody explain why can this be happening?

Edit: we don't have a DHCP server in our network.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with the network driver. What is the model of your NIC? Maybe there is already an updated version from the manufacturer.

Comment: May be true. On the other hand, I'm not an expert but it always seemed to be that the network level drivers should be more or less hardware independent.

Comment: Well put: "should" and "more or less" :-)

Answer (score 0):

What Configuration did you do with the system? I have a similar problem on a Win 2003 STD server, however I reckon when i added it to the domain it began to give me this restriction